# RTSP client using VLC library

Tags: c, vlc, libvlc, rtsp-client

I should write RTSP client in c programming using VLC library , I have some questions about this :

1. I didn't find any already function in VLC library to send RTSP SETUP
   request , should I write it from scratch ?
2. When I send the RTSP SETUP request , I must open 2 sockets for RTP
   and RTCP to send its ports number to live555 media server to receive
   the data through these port , Do you need to open another socket for
   UDP to receive the response of RTSP SETUP/PLAY/PAUSE/STOP request to
   control the transmission data process ?
3. When I want to pause the transmission data process at application
   layer , I should send RTSP PAUSE request to server and send PAUSE
   request to player to stop the transmission data process temporarily, but I don't know what functions in VLC library are used for this
   purpose , can you tell me about  what these functions are?

Thank you.

Comment: VLC does not implement RTSP itself. It deploys liblive555 for this purpose and the respective live555 access module. Basing a RTSP client app on libvlc is absolutely feasible and should work out of the box with no modifications needed.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by feepk in the comments, you do not need to manually do any of the RTSP setup, as VLC does this for you using live555 library. You can open an RTSP connection using the libvlc_media_new_location function, then pass to your media player instance.

For example:

```
// You must create an instance of the VLC Library
libvlc_instance_t * vlc;
// You need a player to play media
libvlc_media_player_t *mediaPlayer;
// Media object to play.
libvlc_media_t *media;

// Configure options for this instance of VLC (global settings).
// See VLC command line documentation for options.
std::vector<const char*> options;
std::vector<const char*>::iterator option;
// Load the VLC engine
vlc = libvlc_new (int(options.size()), options.data());

// Create a media item from URL
media = libvlc_media_new_location (vlc, "RTSP_URL_HERE");
mediaPlayer = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (media);
```